# Sum of select result

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have simple `select` statement that groups broker fees per region from my table transactions.

```
SELECT brokerid AS Broker, sum(brokersfees) AS Fees
FROM transactions
WHERE handelstag>#1/1/2014#
and regionid = 1
GROUP BY brokerid;
```

The result for region 1 would be like this:

```
broker      fees
1             2540
55           26698
882         100000
```

Now I want a sum over this result over all brokers for this region. So adding fees for 1,55, 882 etc.

I did this:

```
SELECT SUM(Fees) AS ALLIN FROM
   (
SELECT brokerid AS Broker, sum(brokersfees) AS Fees
FROM transactions
WHERE handelstag>#1/1/2014#
and regionid = 1
GROUP BY brokerid;
   ) AS t
```

I do get a result, but it is way too high. I confirmed this when I added the results manually.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your date format suggests MS Access, yet the tags on the question are MySQL and SQL Server and the title says MySQL.  What database are you really using?

Comment: Your SQL is correct and should return the expected `100000+26698+2540`. Are you telling us everything?

Comment: sorry guys, yes i am using access. didnt know what sql that was.

Comment: i somehow it seems to add the numbers wrong.

Comment: Your second statement is unnecessarily complex, but it is correct and should be giving you the results you want. Instead you may want to write it as: `SELECT sum(brokerfees) FROM transactions WHERE handelstag>#1/1/2014# and regionid = 1` This way the database doesn't have to do unnecessary aggregation.